# How to remove green from greenscreen video on python?

Tags: python, video

I am doing a project where I am attempting to take out the green screen on a video on python but I do not know how to go about it.
Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use actual video editing software, like Avid or Final Cut?

Comment: Here is a way to do it : http://salgat.blogspot.com/2015/04/using-pythons-pil-library-to-remove.html

Comment: And what have you tried so far?  If you haven't made an attempt or don't have a specific programming question, you're just telling us something you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

well...I presume you have some kind of RGB image for each frame of video. 
I.e an N by 3 array. 
(You could use OpenCV to read each frame.)

So it is case of going through the image and locating all the green and replacing it with what you want. 
E.g if the array is called `arr` then for each row, `i`, you would check whether `arr[i] == [0,255,0]`.

But due to the nature of film, you aren't going to have a perfectly uniform 0,255,0 green. There will be shadows and other slight variations. Perhaps it wasn't even 0,255,0 to start out with.

So you are going to be looking at removing a range of colours. Now for each row we are searching for a range of colours and replacing them with your choice.

We now run the risk of identifying a colour for removal that we don't actually want removing....so how can we check for that...
We still probably won't get a perfect match around the edges (of the objects/people we want to keep in the image), so to make this less obvious, we might want to use a little bit of blur and so on and so forth.

Look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIWoLCFvjME

Try to think about what *logic* code is required for each little step the user takes.
Also think about all the decision the user makes that are purely subjective. Obviously these would be nigh-on impossible to automate reliably. So now we are talking about some kind of interactive application that allows the user to select different actions based on their subjective choice.

And we quickly see why green screen is often removed manually, frame by frame using a powerful editing application like photoshop, after effects etc...

OpenCV (http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) will do a lot of the algorithms for you...there is almost enough there to build your interactive greenscreen removal software...